# Orika: How to map using a nested mapper

Tags: java, converters, mapper, orika

Consider the following situation:

```
public class A {

    private ClassInA classInA;

    public ClassInA getClassInA() {
        return classInA;
    }

    public void setClassInA(ClassInA classInA) {
        this.classInA = classInA;
    }

}

public class B {

    private ClassInB classInB;

    public ClassInB getClassInB() {
        return classInB;
    }

    public void setClassInB(ClassInB classInB) {
        this.classInB = classInB;
    }

}

public class ClassInA {

    private String myString;

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

}

public class ClassInB {

    private String myString;

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

}
```

Now I want to map `A` to `B` using orika. I need a converter to do so. Like:

```
public class MyMapper {

    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
        ConverterFactory converterFactory = factory.getConverterFactory();
        converterFactory.registerConverter(new MyConverter());

        factory.classMap(A.class, B.class) //
                .field("classInA", "classInB") //
                .register();
    }
}

public class MyConverter extends CustomConverter<ClassInA, ClassInB> {

    @Override
    public ClassInB convert(ClassInA source, Type<? extends ClassInB> destinationType) {
        ClassInB classInB = new ClassInB();
        classInB.setMyString(source.getMyString());
        return classInB;
    }

}
```

Although a mapper for `ClassInA` to `ClassInB` would be better. Like:

```
public class MyMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
        factory.classMap(ClassInA.class, ClassInB.class) //
                .byDefault
                .register();
    }
}
```

Sadly I have no clue how to register the mapper in `MyMapper`. There is nothing like `converterFactory.registerMapper(new MyMapper());`. The only way I could do this is via

```
.customize(
    return new CustomMapper<LoanContractRequestValue, LoanContrReqERPCrteReqLoanContr>() {
        @Override
        public void mapAtoB(A source, B destination, MappingContext context) {
            destination.setMyString(source.getMyString());
        }
    };
)
```

But is this really the way to go for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register multiple classMaps in the same mapperFactory, Orika will know which one to use based on the class/type.

```
public class MyMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {
    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
        factory.classMap(A.class, B.class)
                .field("classInA", "classInB")
                .register();

        factory.classMap(ClassInA.class, ClassInB.class)
                .byDefault
                .register();
    }
}
```